# Спікер чи речник - як правильно?

Tags: синоніми, запозичені-слова

Я не раз чув як в новинах вживали таке словосполучення як "спікер Верховної ради", але нещодавно я задумався: "А чому ЗМІ вживають запозичене слово "спікер", якщо в україніській мові є слово "речник"?"

Ось наприклад, назва одніє статті з Радіо Свобода:

> У Зеленського кажуть, що підстави для розпуску Ради є, **спікер** Парубій
>   стверджує – немає

В СУМі є слова "[речник](http://sum.in.ua/s/rechnyk)" та "[спікер](http://sum.in.ua/s/spiker)", однак не пише, що ці слова можуть мати синонімічне значення. Проте на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80) є стаття "Спікер", де пише:

> Спі́кер (англ. Speaker, буквально — оратор, промовець, **речник**) — в
>   західних країнах голова законодавчих зборів, політичного органу,
>   парламенту.

А також пише:

> Термін широко розповсюджений у політичному лексиконі, але **як офіційна
>   назва посади вживається тільки в англомовних країнах**.

Тобто виникає питання - чи правлиьно використовувати слово "спікер" чи все ж таки краще замінити його словом "речник" і чи не буде така заміна помилкою?

Comment: Взагалі думаю, що це пов'язано з середовищем. В певному англомовному середовищі з'являються відповідні говірки. 
Коли людина бере знання з певного одного іноземного ресурсу, то використовуються саме ті слова, які вперше потрапили до словникового запасу із розумінням чогось нового.
Закарбування нового терміну, нового розуміння з іншомовних джерел. Також це пов'язано з неосвіченістю. З незнанням слова рідною мовою. Потрібні інструменті для покращення освіти в цьому напрямку.